# Calculate the sum of subsequent rows for a subset of values

Tags: r

I posted a question earlier on that topic, but I think it was not clear enough. Sorry. So, this is the second try.

I have data on the amount of milk consumed (volume) at different times for different individuals.

```
individual <- c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 6))
time <- c(0, 12, 20, 26, 32, 36, 50, 0, 10, 21, 24, 36, 60)
volume <- c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)
df <- data.frame(individual, time, volume)
```

So, I want to know how much milk is consumed during 24 hours after a milk ingestion. For example, individual A at time 0 h (first line in df) drank 0.3 L of milk and then drank an additionnal 0.2 L at time 12 and 0.1 L at time 20, which gives a total of 0.6 L drank during the 24 hours period following a milk ingestion.

I want to calculate this for every line for each individual and the desired output would be:

```
res_volume <- c(0.6, 1.1, 0.9, 1.0, "NA", "NA", "NA", 1.3, 1.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3, "NA")
df2 <- data.frame(df, res_volume)
```

"NA"s are there because there is not enough data to cover 24 hours after the milk ingestion (the difference in time between the last line for that individual and the given lines is less than 24 hours).

Any idea how I could achieve this? Your answers are really appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you have a matrix rather than a data frame. Also, what is the origin of these dates?

Comment: @Joanie Van De Walle If you have missing values, please don't use "NA". WIll convert the column to character.

Comment: Agreed. In my case, replacing NA by 0 still works, so I changed it.

Comment: @Joanie Van De Walle I think there is some confusion about how the sumvolume is calculated. In the 2nd case `1.4` interval, it is not clear to me how you selected rows `7:10`.  I guess you took rows `2:4` for the `2.2` interval

Comment: The interval column is the difference between subsequent rows of the time column with the first row for each individual having no upper reference and should be "NA" (replaced by 0 here to keep the vector numeric). In the second case, interval of 2.2 days occurred between row 6 and 7, so I sum volume from row 7 (40705.7) until a day later (40706.5) which is row 10. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this function work for you?  You can set the interval at whatever increment you like with the default at 24.

```
milk_iter_sum <- function(df, interval=24){
  res_volume <- vector()
  df_list <- split(df, f=individual)
  for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
    cur_df <- df_list[[i]]
    for(j in 1:(nrow(cur_df))){

      inner_cur_df <- cur_df[cur_df$time >= cur_df$time[j] & cur_df$time<=cur_df$time[j]+interval,]

      if(cur_df$time[nrow(cur_df)] - inner_cur_df$time[1] < interval){
        res_volume <- append(res_volume, NA)
      }else{
        res_volume <- append(res_volume, with(inner_cur_df, aggregate(volume, by = list(individual), sum))$x)  

      }
    }
  }
  return(cbind(df, res_volume))
}

milk_iter_sum(df)

   individual time volume res_volume
1           A    0    0.3        0.6
2           A   12    0.2        1.1
3           A   20    0.1        0.9
4           A   26    0.4        1.0
5           A   32    0.3         NA
6           A   36    0.1         NA
7           A   50    0.2         NA
8           B    0    0.2        1.3
9           B   10    0.4        1.1
10          B   21    0.4        0.9
11          B   24    0.3        0.5
12          B   36    0.2        0.3
13          B   60    0.1         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your meaning, start by identifying the rows which follow a "long interval" :

```
therows<- which(df$interval>1)+1
```

Then

```
df[therows,c(1,2,4)]
```

should be your desired result

Comment: Thanks, however it does not give the sum of volumes within 24 hours after the selected rows.

Comment: I see yr point. Strictly speaking, that can't be calculated w/out interpolation, but I think one can mod this code to sum enough rows to exceed 1.0 days.  Use `cumsum` repeatedly starting at each value of `therows`, perhaps.